# Binary search tree recursion does not work

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree

I created this binary search tree. I wrote the insert method in 2 forms using loop and recursion. The recursion code although seems correct but does not work and I cannot figure out what the problem is. When I create the tree using insertRecursion method, the leftChild and rightChild always are null.

```
public class BinarySearchTree {
private class Node{
    private int value;
    private Node leftChild;
    private Node rightChild;
    public Node(int value){
        this.value=value;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return ""+this.value;
    }
}
private Node root;
public BinarySearchTree(int value){
    root=new Node(value);
}
public void insertRecursion(int value){
    Node current=root;
    insertRecursionForm(current,value);
}
private Node insertRecursionForm(Node root, int value){
    if(root==null){
        root=new Node(value);
        return root;
    }
    if(value<root.value){
        return insertRecursionForm(root.leftChild,value);
    }else{
        return insertRecursionForm(root.rightChild,value);
    }
}

public void insert(int value){
    Node current=root;
    while(true) {
        if (value < current.value) {
            if (current.leftChild == null) {
                current.leftChild= new Node(value);
                break;
            }else{
                current=current.leftChild;
            }
        }else if(value>current.value) {
            if (current.rightChild == null) {
                current.rightChild= new Node(value);
                break;
            }else{
                current=current.rightChild;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You don't need a separate `Node` class. Every node of the tree is a `BInarySearchTree`. Try it that way and everything will become clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
private Node insertRecursionForm(Node root, int value){
    if(root==null){
        root=new Node(value);
        return root;
    }
    if(value<root.value)
    {
        root.leftChild = insertRecursionForm(root.leftChild,value);
    }else
    {
        root.rightChild = insertRecursionForm(root.rightChild,value);
    }
    return root;
}
```

The problem with your previous code was that you only returned the value of the last inserted node. This is why you always had the left and right node be null.